# Finding the Maximum and Minimum of Trigonometric Equations By Quadratic Substitution

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, polynomials

$$y=3\cos2x + 7\sin x +2$$

The original question was: Finding the stationary point of the function.
I tried to use both differentiation and trigonometric substitution of $\cos(2x)$ into $1-2\sin^2(x)$.

For the quadratic method, I substituted $\sin(x)$ as $u$ and solved for $u$, where the  the equation is equated to $0$, and finding the midpoint of the roots to find out the value of $x$ following the nature of a parabolic equation.

Unfortunately I realized that trigonometric substitution eliminates a possible solution for $x$ where $\cos(x) =0$. I suspect that it might be due to a non function being converted into a function but I do not quite understand why does it causes so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the substitution, you get the quadratic $$5+7u-6u^2,$$ for $-1\le u\le 1.$ This has a maximum of $169/24,$ where $u=7/12,$ and a minimum of $-8,$ where $u=-1.$

Hence if there are no points of inflection where the curve is stationary, then the stationary points occur where $\sin x=-1,$ or where $\sin x=7/12.$ One may then solve these for the possible values of $x,$ if one so wishes.

Comment: Yes ! This was the answer I was looking for. I wasn't aware that if u was a trigonometric ratio it would directly place a maximum on the parabolic curve maximum was caused by the character of trigonometric ratios not having a domain exceeding -1. This was very clarifying. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First impulse is to
just differentiate.

$y=3\cos2x + 7\sin x +2
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
y'
&=-6\sin(2x) + 7\cos x\\
&=-12\sin(x)\cos(x) + 7\cos x\\
&=\cos(x)(-12\sin(x) + 7)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\cos(x) = 0$
or
$\sin(x) = \dfrac{7}{12}
$.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to 
$$ y=5+7\sin x-6\sin^2x $$
and substituting $u=\sin x$ gives
$$y=5+7u-6u^2$$

So

$$ \frac{dy}{du}=7-12u $$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{du}=7-12u $$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=(7-12u)\frac{du}{dx}=0 $$
$$ (7-12u)\cos x=0 $$

So you don't actually lose the $\cos x$.

Comment: What if I solved y as a quadratic equation? So I equate y = 0, then find values of u where

Comment: What if I immediately use $$y=5+7u-6u^2$$ and solved for u when y=0? Then solved $u =\frac{-b}{2a}$ ? Why would it lose a factor of $$ cos x = 0 $$

Comment: The stationary points are not where $y=0$, they are where $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Just directly differentiate so that it includes all automatically. $[ (s,c)= \sin ..,\cos ..]$
$$ y= 5+7s-6s^2$$
$$ 0= (7-12s)\,c$$
$$ c=0,s=\frac{7}{12}.$$